# Open Layers squished tiles until page zoomed

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Upon initial load the map tiles are squished or sometimes do not appear properly as per image below. This is fixed when the page is zoomed in and out (not the map).

This is when the page is viewed on a 2K screen, any suggestions for how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: It is only with your pages or do you have the same problem other pages? e.g. the OpenLayers examples https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/simple.html

Comment: It is only with my pages, as far as I can tell this is also limited to when I am developing locally, once the code has been packaged the problem seems to disappear.

Comment: It could be an incompatibility between OpenLayers and your zoomable display, particularly if you are attempting a full screen map.  The examples all include `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">` (it's in the pages when you view source, but not in the example code) to fix the viewport.  Be sure to include it if you haven't already.

Comment: Yeah I have that set, thanks for the suggestion though, not sure why someone downvoted this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still unsure why this occurs, however I found that calling the **updateSize** method on the map once loading has completed fixes the issue.

I am using this within a method I use to track when the tiles have loaded:

```
checkTilesLoaded() {
    let totalStarted = 0;
    let totalLoaded = 0;

    this.state.source.on('tileloadstart', () => {
        totalStarted += 1;
    });

    this.state.source.on('tileloaderror', () => {
        totalLoaded += 1;

        if (totalLoaded === totalStarted) tilesLoaded();
    });

    this.state.source.on('tileloadend', () => {
        totalLoaded += 1;

        if (totalLoaded === totalStarted) tilesLoaded();
    });

    const tilesLoaded = () => {

        this.map.updateSize();

        this.setState({
            mapLoaded: true
        });
    }
}
```